# Given this MLB algorithm, how do I predict a winner?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics

### Understanding The Algorithm

I am interested in incorporating an algorithm that supposedly is somewhat accurate in predicting a baseball game winner. Some guy named Whisnant came up with this algorithm, explained here: https://www.news.iastate.edu/news/2010/feb/baseball

```
W1/L1 = (RPG1/RPG2)^a (SLG1/SLG2)^b

where: a = 0.723 (RPG1 + RPG2)^.373 
and b = 0.977 (RPG1 + RPG2)^( -.947)
```

> **RPG** is RUNS PER GAME
>
> **SLG** is SLUGGING PERCENTAGE ( total bases divided by at bats )

***I have NO IDEA what W1 / L1 means.***

So I have the following CSV data for every MLB game in 2019:

1. Date  => Example: 04012019
2. Home Team
3. Visit Team
4. Day of Week => Returns 0-6
5. Home Score
6. Visit Score
7. Home Team Earned Runs
8. Visit Team Earned Runs
9. Home Errors
10. Visit Errors
11. Home Hits
12. Home Walks
13. Home Strikeouts
14. Visit Hits
15. Visit Walks
16. Visit Strikeouts

### Best Approach?

Given the fact I have those stats available, does anyone know how I could use that info to come up with a decent prediction? Maybe even just getting Whisnant's formula to work?

Thank you.

Comment: this article may help - its not quite a simple calculation but a distribution where you have to analyze each team individually then to each other

https://towardsdatascience.com/markov-chain-analysis-and-simulation-using-python-4507cee0b06e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context i'd assume that `W1/L1` is predicted win/loss ratio for team 1. E.G. a score of 3 would mean that chances are 3:1 they win, you could test this by swapping teams it should always be `W1/L1 = 1/(W2/L2)`

Comment: Ok, so I plugged in some test values: 

 RPG1 = 5;
        RPG2 = 6;

        slg1 = 10/60;
        slg2 = 11/65;

        a =  0.723 *(RPG1 + RPG2)^.373;
        b =  0.977 *(RPG1 + RPG2)^( -.947);
        v = (RPG1/RPG2)^a * (slg1/slg2)^b;
        
        alert(v);

I am getting 12 as a response.  So how is this number relevant? Let's assume team1 is BOSTON REDSOX, team2 is the YANKEES.  How does "12" tell me anything related to who predicted to win? Do I have to run the same algorithm reversed, and compare the numbers?